# Cannot to setup environment for Hadoop installation in Windows

Tags: maven, hadoop

I want to setup the Hadoop environment. I follow the tutorial from this site: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/branches/branch-2/BUILDING.txt?view=markup

I've manage to setup the jdk, maven, protocolbuffer.
Then i run the command mvn package [-Pdist][-Pdocs][-Psrc][-Dtar]
But was fail and got the error below. I'm not understand with it. Whats the problem? And how to fix it??

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 29.110 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-09T20:12:17+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/168M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.8
.1:jar (module-javadocs) on project hadoop-annotations: MavenReportException: Er
ror while creating archive:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\hadoop-annotations\src\main
\java\org\apache\hadoop\classification\InterfaceStability.java:27: error: unexpe
cted end tag: </ul>
[ERROR] * </ul>
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Command line was: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre\..\bin\javadoc.
exe" @options @packages
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Refer to the generated Javadoc files in 'C:\hdfs\hadoop-common-project\h
adoop-annotations\target' dir.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
xception
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :hadoop-annotations
C:\hdfs>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a line -Xdoclint:none to your global properties section.